# how to get $f(t,y)$ function of Verhulst differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

Take the Verhulst logistic differential equation down blew:

$$I'(t) = \beta I(t)\left(1-\dfrac {I(t)}N \right)$$

with beta an N as constants.
How can I write this equation as a f(t,y) equation int the form of y'(t)=f(t,y(t)) (here y(t)=I(t))?
I want to write in this function so I can calculate partial derivative of it and see the existence and uniqueness of the solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's already in the form you want

Comment: Your $I(t)$ is $y(t)$ and $f(t,y(t))=\beta y(t)(1-\frac{y(t)}{N})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$I'(t) = \beta I(t)\left(1-\dfrac {I(t)}N \right)$$
$$I'(t) = \beta \left(I(t)-\dfrac {I^2(t)}N \right)$$
It's alreay in the form:
$$y'=f(t,y)$$
Here $y(t)=I(t)$

For the derivative with respect to $I$
$$\dfrac {\partial }{\partial I}  \beta \left(I(t)-\dfrac {I^2(t)}N \right)= \beta \left(1-\dfrac {2I(t)}N \right)$$